# Ambassador Edge Stack Questions

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, ambassador

I'm getting no healthy upstream error. when accessing ambassador. Pods/Services and Loadbalancer seems to be all fine and healthy. Ambassador is on top of aks.

At the moment I have got multiple services running in the Kubernetes cluster and each service has it's on Mapping with its own prefix.  Is it possible to point out multiple k8s services to the same mapping so that I don't have too many prefixes? And all my k8s services will be under the same ambassador prefix?

By Default ambassador is taking me through https which is creating certificate issues, although I will be bringing https in near future for now I'm just looking to prove the concept so how can I disable HTTPS and do HTTP only ambassador?

Answer (score 1):

1. No healthy upstream typically means that, for whatever reason, Ambassador cannot find the service listed in the mapping.  The first thing I usually do when I see this is to run `kubectl exec -it -n ambassador {my_ambassador_pod_name} -- sh` and try to `curl -v my-service` where "my-service" is the Kube DNS name of the service you are trying to hit.  Depending on the response, it can give you some hints on why Ambassador is failing to see the service.
2. Mappings work on a 1-1 basis with services.  If your goal, however, is to avoid prefix usage, there are other ways Ambassador can match to create routes.  One common way I've seen is to use host-based routing (https://www.getambassador.io/docs/latest/topics/using/headers/host/) and create subdomains for either individual or logical sets of services.
3. AES defaults to redirecting to HTTPS, but this behavior can be overwritten by applying a host with insecure routing behavior.  A very simple one that I commonly use is this:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Host
metadata:
  name: wildcard
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  hostname: "*"
  acmeProvider:
    authority: none
  requestPolicy:
    insecure:
      action: Route
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      hostname: wildcard
```